# How do I select Edit Mode after I imported an SVG into Blender 2.79b?

Tags: edit-mode, object-mode

After I imported the SVG file, it automatically entered Object Mode. When I select the Object Mode drop-down, there are no options other than Object Mode. I am specifically trying to correct the faces/spaces reversal problem, but can't get out of Object Mode to Edit Mode. Tab doesn't switch between the modes.

Comment: How are you selecting it, is there an active object? Try clicking on one of the imported objects first

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I chose Select > Select All By Layer and the object is selected. This is on a Mac, if that makes any difference.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I now have Edit Mode in the Object dropdown. I have no idea what made the difference. I did duplicate the object.

Comment: You can only edit one object at the time. Selecting all will not work you need a single active object. With an active object you can enter edit mode.

Comment: Selecting with patterns via Shift+G or selecting all doesn't make any object as active which is needed in order to start editing it

Answer (score 2):

After importing the SVG you need to right click it in 3D view or left click it in Outliner. Then you will be able to Tab into Edit Mode without issues.

Comment: Clicking makes it active. Select all, even with only one object present in the scene, does not? OK.